# Use of bash program with argument inside a sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have a small SED question to ask you.
But first of all, I know there are other ways to do what I want (I've already made a small python script to do that), but for my own curiosity, I'd like to know if there is a way to do that with SED.

So, e.g. : here is a CSV file like :

```
12345678,yan solo
23456789,luke skywalker
34567890,leia organa
```

And here is a bash script named "SOMESCRIPT", which will transform a argument in something else.  E.g. :

```
~$ ./SOMESCRIPT 12345678
abcd
```

So, what I'd like to di is : use that script from inside a SED to regenerate the CSV with converted value.

Here an example of output :

```
abcd,yan solo
efgh,luke skywalker
ijkl,leia organa
```

**Some thinkings :**

```
~$ cat somecsv.csv | sed "s/\(.*\),/\1/g"
```

*--> The regex catch the part to be transformed and save it to the stack in \1*

```
~$ cat somecsv.csv | sed "s/\(.*\),/`SOMESCRIPT `\1/g"
```

*--> For each line, SOMESCRIPT is executed, but before the printing of \1*

```
~$ cat somecsv.csv | sed "s/\(.*\),/`SOMESCRIPT \1`/g"
```

*--> For each line, SOMESCRIPT is executed, but \1 is not recognized as a shell variable*

**So, basicaly, the question is : is it possible to pass the stack value \1 as a shell argument to SOMESCRIPT ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\(,.*\)/printf "%s\2\\n" $(SOMESCRIPT "\1")/e' file
```

This uses the GNU specific `e` flag/command. If you remove it from the substitution command the output from sed command can be piped into a bash command which does the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

With `GNU` sed you can pass the `e` option to `s` command which makes sed execute the result of the substitution as a shell command:

```
sed 's#.*#./SOMESCRIPT "\0"#e'
```

You can also  use `awk` for the job. From within an awk program you can use the `system()` function to execute an external command through a shell:

```
awk -F, '{system("./SOMESCRIPT \""$1"\"")}'
```

The shell itself can also do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="," read a b c ; do
    ./SOMESCRIPT "$a"
done < some.csv
```

After all I favour the shell solution since it properly escapes the argument of `SOMESCRIPT` - by design.

Comment: Much cleaner to do this in shell itself +1

Comment: Yes. After all, I also came to that conclusion.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  that doesn't exactly work the way I want, but it's a good starting point

Comment: and thanks for the alternative like awk and while, I know that can work, but the initial question was to do that using SED.